# how to aggregating json response?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to aggregate a json response from a stored procedure.

below is the actual response from proc.

```
[
{
    "type": "fruit",
    "name": "apple"
},

{
    "type": "animal",
    "name": "cat"
},
{
    "type": "fruit",
    "name": "orange"
},
{
    type: "animal",
    "name": "dog"
}
]
```

after aggregation i want it to be some thing like this,

```
[
{
    "type":"fruit",
    "name":["apple","orange"]
},

{
    "type":"animal",
    "name":["cat","dog"]
}
]
```

can any one please help me with the best solution possible ?

thanks,

Comment: Have a look at jq https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: why would you use an array and not just an object? `{ "fruit" : ["apple", "orange"], "animal" : "name":["cat","dog"] }`

Comment: coz thats how i am getting data from a stored procedure...

Comment: I am saying why would you want the combined output in that format and not like how I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

**This should do it:**

```
function foo(data) {
    var i, d, temp = {}, output=[];
    for (i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        d = data[i];
        if (d["type"] in temp)
            temp[d['type']].push(d['name']);
        else
            temp[d['type']] = [d['name']];
    }
    for (d in temp) {
        output.push({
            'type': d,
            'name': temp[d]
        });
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6cbpon3c/) to a running example on jsFiddle.